# Изменение формата номера телефона

Tags: excel

Не получается обновить формат ячеек. Присутствуют номера телефонов в следующем формате:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно привести их к виду :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После добавления формата cледующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обновляется только первая ячейка, для обновления формата по остальным-нужно выбирать каждую ячейку и нажимать enter.

Подскажите, как обновить все ячейки сразу? Пробовал выбрать ячейку в нужном формате и применить ко всем остальным через `cntrl+alt+v`, однако вставляется не формат ячейки, а она на место всех остальных.

Comment: Перед изменением формата выделить диапазон (или весь столбец), а не ячейку. Кстати, значение в ячейке не меняется, меняется только его визуальное представление

Comment: Имеете ввиду способ  через cntrl+alt+v?

Comment: Правый клик на названии столбца - столбец выделен. Задаем формат

Comment: В ячейках текстовые данные, не числа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Формат ячеек, который задается, работает с числовыми данными. А в ячейках, похоже, числа, представленные в текстовом формате. Это могло случиться по разным причинам: при загрузке со сторонних программ; если формат столбца перед вводом данных задан как *Текстовый*; если данные получены формулой, которая возвращает текст...

Следует заметить, что формат ячейки и формат значения - не одно и то же.

Проверить формат:

- В левом верхнем углу ячейки зеленый треугольник информирует о том, что число сохранено как текст. Эта индикация может быть отключена в параметрах.
- Расширить столбец; если данные прижаты к левой стороне ячеек - текст. Но это не показатель, если в ячейках уже задано горизонтальное выравнивание.
- Формулой `=ЕТЕКСТ(ссылка)`  или `=ЕЧИСЛО(ссылка)`

Лечим.

Проверить формат ячеек. Изменить, если *Текстовый*. Если данные получены формулой, нужно что-то менять в формуле.

Выделить диапазон с данными, вкладка *Данные-Текст по столбцам-ОК*. Текстовые числовые значения преобразуются в числа. После этого можно задать формат ячеек для всего диапазона.

Привести данные к нужному формату (формат данных, не ячейки!) можно в другом столбце формулой:

```
=ТЕКСТ(A2;"+7"" ""(#)"" ""000-00-00")
```

Comment: Данные копировались из sql server и действительно были в текстовом формате. Cпасибо!